# How to make search based on pickup date and return date?

Tags: php, mysql

In the car page,i already input all the data into mysql database(car table).So i want to ease the user to find the car that available on pickup date and return date.So,I made search pickup date and return date in search page.But the error is "could not be execute".

This is using mysql and php.

car.php

```
</body>
        <table align='center' width='40%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <form action="search.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <td><input type="date" name="Pickup_date" placeholder="Pickup_date" style='height:38px' required /></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="Return_date" placeholder="Return_date" style='height:38px' required    /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submitbook" value="Search" style='background-color: blue; border: none; color: white; padding: 10px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px;'/></td>
    </div>
                </form>
            </table>

 <?php

 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "online_car_rental");

 // Check connection
 if($link === false){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


 // Attempt select query execution
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM car";
 if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
 echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Id</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Price(RM)</th>";
    echo "<th>Colour</th>";
    echo "<th>Mode</th>";
    echo "<th>Image</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>Add to Booking</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_colour'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_mode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='" . $row['car_image'] . "' height='100' 
    width='100'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car_status'] . "</td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="pickup_date" 
  value="'.$pickup_date.'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_date" 
  value="'.$return_date.'">';
    echo "<td><button onclick=\"booking_car('" . $row['car_id'] . 
    "')\">Book</button>
    </td>";

  echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
 } else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }

 mysqli_close($link);
?>

 </html>
```

search.php

```
 <?php

 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "online_car_rental");

 if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$search=$_GET['s'];
$query="SELECT * FROM car WHERE date BETWEEN 'pickup_date' AND 
 'return_date'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Id</th>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Price(RM)</th>";
            echo "<th>Colour</th>";
            echo "<th>Mode</th>";
            echo "<th>Image</th>";
            echo "<th>Status</th>";
            echo "<th>Add to Booking</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_price'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_colour'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_mode'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='" . $row['car_image'] . "' height='100' width='100'></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['car_status'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pickup_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['return_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><button onclick=\"booking_car('" . $row['car_id'] . 
    "')\">Book</button>

    </td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
 } else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>

</html>
```

i expect the output is based on pickup_date and return_date.But the output is "ERROR:Could not able to execute".

Comment: `$query="SELECT * FROM car WHERE date BETWEEN 'pickup_date' AND 
 'return_date'";` I don't see you passing a date. That might cause a MySQL error. Post the error from MySQL itself

Answer (score 2):

You Can check with this , When you have two tables you can use inner join query to fetch the data

```
SELECT columns
FROM table WHERE pickup_date < 'your_pickup_date' AND return_date >= 'your_pickup_date' ORDER
BY  car or date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your schema, it's difficult to provide a detailed solution, but an example of a plausible query might be as follows:

```
"    
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM car c
 WHERE pickup_date < :return_date
   AND return_date >= :pickup_date
 ORDER
    BY pickup_date
     , car_id;
"
```